# What CultureInfo or NumberFormat should I use to create html/css percentages with double.ToString?

Tags: c#, html, css, tostring

I'm writing an ASP.Net MVC4 web application, and I want to calculate the size of some elements using C#.

However, I'm having some trouble because css will only accept percentages as `xx.yy%`, that is with a point as the decimal separator, and no space before the percent symbol (as far as I have discovered).

The problem is, I can't find any C# culture that produces this kind of percentages. It seems that English (US) produces the right decimal separator, while German uses the percent symbol correctly (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
Culture:                  English (United States)
(P) Percent:. . . . . . . -123,456.70 %
Culture:                  German (Germany)
(P) Percent:. . . . . . . -123.456,70%
```

Is there one Culture or NumberFormat that is recommended for this, or at least one that consistently works? Or do I need to write my own, and how would I go ahead to do that?

Comment: why are the numbers coming out of MVC formatted at all? percentages can only be -99.99 to 99.99, don't use "toString" maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your custom extension method:

```
public static string ToPercentageString(this double d)
{
    return d.ToString("p", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace(" ", string.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
double number = 0.8623;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("#0.##%"));
```

This should produce 86.23% (with dot, no space before % sign)

Comment: My problem is, that as long as I don't specify a culture, it's gonna use my Norwegian one, which inserts a comma, even though a dot is explicitly specified. InvariantCulture seems to work, though!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your own custom format string:

```
using System.Globalization;
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        double d = 12.345;
        string s = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0.00}%", d);
    }
}
```

Here are some output examples of numeric format strings: [Custom Numeric Format Strings Output Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x5bacwt%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)